# How to replay message by irazasyed telegram freamwork in Laravel 5.0 setwebhook

Tags: laravel, telegram-bot

I used Laravel 5.0 and Irazasyed telegram bot, I want work by webhook and when a person send message to telegram bot, the telegram send a message automatically to that.

My code is here bot not worked by webhook:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Technical;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Url;

use Telegram\Bot\Api;

use Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram;

use Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $telegram = new Api('117451573:*********************', 'true');
        $telegram->setWebhook(['url' => 'https://******.com/117451573:********************/webhook']);
        $update = $telegram->getWebhookUpdates();

        $telegram->sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => '********',
            'text' => 'thanks',
        ]);
        return response()->json(["status" => "success"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) for tips on increasing the chance of getting attention and an answer for your question.

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to get [Irazasyed's Telegram Bot SDK](https://irazasyed.github.io/telegram-bot-sdk/usage/initial-setup/) to work as well. Heres a tutorial: [Let's make a Telegram bot with PHP](http://www.ntaso.com/lets-make-a-telegram-bot-with-php/), that seems to be up to date. I had not the time to test it by myself. Will come hopefully the next days.

To use webhooks its seems you have to call the following command in the shell once.

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"url":"https://www.example.com/my-secret-webhook.php"}' https://api.telegram.org/botYOUR_BOT_TOKEN/setWebhook
```

see chapter *II. Configuring the Webhook* at the tutorial.

Good luck